# Meaning of a certain Kronecker pairing.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a compact oriented manifold of dimension $n$ with fundamental class $[M]$. Consider the image of $[M]$ under the map $H_n(M)\rightarrow H_n(M\times M)$ induced by the diagonal map, and let $\alpha\in H^n(M\times M)$ be the Poincaré dual. Does the Kronecker Pairing $<\alpha\cup\alpha,[M\times M]>$ carry a topological meaning?

Edit: It has been claimed in the comments that this is $\chi(M)$, so I am looking for a reference including a proof of this NOT USING smooth manifolds.

Comment: It is the Euler characteristic of the manifold, for which there is a plethora of topological interpretations.

Comment: @ThomasRot do you happen to know a reference for this fact? I didn't find this in any book on algebraic topology

Comment: I would refer to bott and tu which is smooth manifolds. Another guess is that is in Bredon's book.

Comment: The usual proof interprets this class as the intersection of the zero section of the tangent bundle with any nonzero class transverse to it.

Comment: Which is not available in the non smooth setting

Comment: @ThomasRot Thanks for the reference. Do you think it the theorem also holds in the not necessarily smooth setting?